# How to get the Expire time of redis cache

Tags: php, redis, predis

How to get the expire date from a  , I am using [Predis](https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis) to cache the data in hash format.
Sample : 
$redis->hset("taxi_car", "brand", "Toyota");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TTL` or `PTTL` to get the remaining time to live of the key, i.e. *taxi_car*. The difference is that the latter returns TTL in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks it works but i am looking for a way to do it using predis php library.

Comment: predis should have something like: `$redis->ttl("taxi_car")`, you can try it.